# SFDX Error: Selected Components Are Not Available

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

Recently, my colleagues started receiving error an error whenever attempting to retrieve or diff components, for production or any of our sandboxes.

[image: Error when attempting to retrieve or diff metadata]]

I have recently joined the team, and I did not receive the error upon a fresh install. However, I had not yet connected my SFDX project to Github. Attempts to retrieve from orgs fail from any branch, including older branches that had no such issues mere weeks ago.

We have updated the CLI, downgraded the CLI, re-authorized the orgs, and reinstalled VS Code. Online solutions don't refer to this exact error message, other than [this unresolved Salesforce issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002SSc9QAG) (the component doesn't seem to matter).

We are using the default sfdx project file structure, with this sfdx-project.json:

```
   {
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
}
```

Comment: how are you retrieving Metadata components? by using package.xml or org browser?

Comment: @sdandamud1 The error occurs via both methods.