# VS Code Diff against Org not working anymore - retrieve still works

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, org, diff

Since a few days I am not able to compare my code to that the of the Sales Cloud server anymore via "SFDX: Diff File against Org".
I receive this error message in VS Code:

> 09:15:09.774 Starting SFDX: Diff File Against Org
> Selected components are not available in the org

However, my Org has been authorized, and I can still retrieve and deploy from VS Code to Sales Cloud.

I checked the sfdx log file in C:\Users<username>.sf by increasing the log level to debug:

```
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"Started metadata transfer. ID = 09S3O000002d5k5UAA","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:57.824Z","v":0}
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"Polling for metadata transfer status. ID = 09S3O000002d5k5UAA","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:57.824Z","v":0}
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"Polling frequency (ms): 100","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:57.824Z","v":0}
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"Polling timeout (min): 60","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:57.824Z","v":0}
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"MDAPI status update: InProgress","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:57.964Z","v":0}
{"name":"sf","hostname":"c90c1c08","pid":13976,"log":"MetadataApiRetrieve","level":20,"msg":"MDAPI status update: Succeeded","time":"2022-11-18T08:17:58.396Z","v":0}
```

According to the log I assume that the sfdx retrieve did work successfully.

Next we checked the folder C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp.sfdx\diff for activity while running the "SFDX: Diff File Against Org" function. No files or folder have been created within this folder.

Then we tried to create a folder and a text file in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp.sfdx\diff manually.
The permissions were set correctly and it succeeded. However, when running "SFDX: Diff File Against Org" again the manually created folders and files disappeared while no new files were created.

Testing the function on a laptop of a colleague we found that for him the files to diff were created within subfolders of C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp.sfdx\diff.

The difference known to us for these two laptops is that the one that is not working is behind a firewall with a proxy, while the one working is without firewall and proxy. However, we believe that this should not be relevant since the retrieve works and there is also no error in the sfdx log.
All the plugins are up-to-date.

Are there any ideas to what the cause of the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have the latest `sfdx` CLI version and the latest VSCode Salesforce plugins?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! You first say that you cannot diff "anymore," but later state something about a laptop behind a firewall. Were you able to correctly diff previously on one machine, and now you cannot diff on the same machine? Or have you never been able to diff on this machine?

Comment: @PhilW: yes, the versions are up-to-date.

Comment: @Moonpie: Correct, I have been able to diff on this machine before. I cannot tell whether it is since the latest plugin update or since the switch to salesforce enhanced domains. Both changes happened at the same time.

Comment: Sanity check: The folders/files you are trying to diff do have the correct/corresponding `*.object-meta.xml` file?

Comment: There is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002SSc9QAG) logged with Salesforce. My org currently has a support ticket open. I submitted [a similar issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389202/sfdx-error-selected-components-are-not-available?noredirect=1#comment562578_389202) on here last week. Our workaround is that retrieving and diffing works when we create a project without an associated Github account, but this may not apply to your scenario. But I'll be sure to chime in if there's some resolution provided to us by Salesforce support.

Comment: @Moonpie: yes, the meta.xml files are there and correct. When I do the retrieve they are being updated together with the corresponding object.